# creating user interface for casperjs

Tags: user-interface, casperjs

I have created casperjs tests on my mac which I run locally on my machine using the command line and calling each one of them. What I want to do is creating a user interface (ie getting rid of the command line) so that anyone can select any number of tests from within the ones that I ve written and and get the output of the tests on the UI. I dont really mind if the UI is a python program, a js-html or anything. I just want it to be flexible enough to do what is requested. Can anyone point me to any good sources where I can get some ideas? Also I ve seen that it gets pretty tricky trying to execute shell commands and getting the output on the UI. Any suggestions on that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to accomplish that using a very simple HTML/PHP page. It sends a shell command to be executed and then(when the whole test has finished) it displays the output. make sure to use the `--no-colors` as ascii code symbols are going to make the output difficult to read.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

        putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/phantomjs");
        exec('/path/to/casperjs test --no-colors /path/to/casperTest.js $user_input 2>&1',$output);

        foreach ($output as $value) {
          echo "$value <br>";
        }
    ?>
</body>
```